# How to display specific columns in html table using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, html-table

i have below code in App.js

I am getting 50 columns from the source, where as i want to display only 4 columns in a table.
when i approach below method, the UI is displaying blank rows than data.

can you help.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const App = () => {

    //1 create useState
    const [employees, setEmployees] = useState([]);

    //2 call api
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("api/employee/GetEmployees")
            .then(response => { return response.json() })
            .then(responseJson => {
                //console.log(responseJson)
                setEmployees(responseJson)
            })
    }, [])

    console.log(employees)
    //console.log(setEmployees)
    //console.log(useState([]))

    //3 create div and table
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <h1>PPMDs</h1>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-sm-12">
                    <table className="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>PPMD ID</th>
                                <th>PPMD Name</th>
                                <th>PPMD</th>
                                <th>Email Address</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody>
                            {
                                employees.map((item) => (
                                    <tr key={item.PersonnelNumber}>
                                        <td>{item.PersonnelNumber}</td>
                                        <td>{item.FirstName}</td>
                                        <td>{item.Type}</td>
                                        <td>{item.EmailAddress}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                ))
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
        
        )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: First off, having that sort of API work in your component violates SOLID principles. Second, you're not supposed to send excessive data over the wire (it screws your app performance if you throw away 90% of the kilobytes you've downloaded). And the last, the thing you've been after is likely filtering out data records which have no values for properties that correspond to your table columns. So, you can get rid of them doing something, like `responseJson.filter(item => ['PersonnelNumber', 'PersonnelNumber', 'FirstName', 'Type', 'EmailAddress'].some(prop => item[prop]))`.

Answer (score 1):

i found the solution for it.
it is the camel case of the column names is casing the issue.
also the way we represent the columns should be enclosed in double quotes.
here is the updated body code.

```
                         <tbody>
                            {
                                employees.map((item) => (
                                    <tr key={item["personnelNumber"]}>
                                        <td>{item["personnelNumber"]}</td>
                                        <td>{item["firstName"] + ', ' + item["lasttName"]}</td>
                                        <td>{item["type"]}</td>
                                        <td>{item["emailAddress"]}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                ))
                            }
                        </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like nothing wrong with this code. I tried to reproduce it, passing a list of objects with the same values you try to retrieve and it returns me a table with a row per item.

Despite this, however, i see that you are fetching your api like this:

```
fetch("api/employee/GetEmployees")
```

Did you config a proxy server like explained here? https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/

Otherwise you are missing the first part of the url, in your GET request. I'm expecting something like this:

```
fetch("http://localhost:PORT/api/employee/GetEmployees")
```

Comment: I am able to get the data from server in Json format and i tested it using
http://localhost:PORT/api/employee/GetEmployees

however, i am not able to display it in the table by field names.

otherwise, i was able to display the row data as is from the feed, that is 50+ columns in the table. the issue is with only the specific column display.